# how to upload csv file and echo json_encode($csv)?

Tags: php, csv

html

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="csv" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" /></form>
</form>
```

I need help reading values from csv that is uploaded. and  echo json_encode($csv). I have trouble getting the values. What I tried was giving me null.

```
<?php
$csv = array();

// check there are no errors
if($_FILES['csv']['error'] == 0){
    $name = $_FILES['csv']['name'];
    $ext = strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES['csv']['name'])));
    $type = $_FILES['csv']['type'];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

    // check the file is a csv
    if($ext === 'csv'){
        if(($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
            // necessary if a large csv file
            set_time_limit(0);


            while(($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
                // number of fields in the csv
                $col_count = count($data);

                // get the values from the csv


            }
array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
    $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});
array_shift($csv); # remove column header
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($csv); //display array
            fclose($handle);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

sample csv

```
LastName,FirstName,MAT251-Calc-I ,MAT252-Calc-II,MAT320-DiscreteMath,CPS210-CompSci-I,CPS310-CompSci-II,CPS315-CompSci-III,CPS352-OOP,CPS330-Assembly.Arch.,CPS353-SoftEng,CPS415-Disc.Cont.Algorithms,CPS340-Op.Sys,CPS425-Lang.Processing,CPS493-Elect-1,CPS493-Projects,EGC230-Dig.Logic,EGC208-Dig.Logic.Lab,SCIENCE-I,SCIENCE-II
Rocha, Cara I.,A,A,A,C-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Hamilton, Mufutau N.,B,B,B,A-,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Castro, Chiquita A.,B,B,C ,C ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Juarez, Edward Y.,C+,B,B,C,A,C+,B,B,C,A,C+,B,B,C,A,C+,A,B
Erickson, Norman H.,C-,B-,C+,B,B,B,,C-,B,,,,,,,B,,
Downs, Moana C.,A,C+,B,C-,A,C-,,A-,B+,,,,,,,,,
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that much code, try this instead:

Save the uploaded file as instructed at [Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php), then:

```
$file="sample.csv";
$csv= file_get_contents($file);
$array = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csv));
$json = json_encode($array);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
print_r($json);
```

---

---

**Functions:**

[file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

> This function is similar to file(), except that file_get_contents()
>   returns the file in a string, starting at the specified offset up to
>   maxlen bytes. On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.

[array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

> Returns an array containing all the elements of array1 after applying
>   the callback function to each one. The number of parameters that the
>   callback function accepts should match the number of arrays passed to
>   the array_map()

[str_getcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

> Parses a string input for fields in CSV format and returns an array
>   containing the fields read.

[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

> Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.

Comment: Enable error reporting to your php code by appending `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: what i am trying to do is upload a csv file. It can be any csv file that has the same structure as a sample csv.